kubernetes 1.30 - ImagePullback error while creating dynamic external provisioner
iam new to kubernetes , pls help to resolve the issue.
Cluster information:
Kubernetes version: 1.30
Cloud being used: NO ( on prem installation ) 1 master 2 worker node
Installation method: manual
Host OS: Linux Redhat 8.5
CNI and version: calico , cniVersion": “0.3.1”
CRI and version: containerd://1.6.33
i am trying to create dynamic external provisioner , following it up the git hub url
https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/nfs-subdir-external-provisioner.
when ever i run this command i end with error, could not create container.
helm install nfs-provisioner 
nfs-subdir-external-provisioner/nfs-subdir-external-provisioner 
--set nfs.10.1.1.1 
--set nfs.path=/ifs/vm
Normal   Scheduled  17m                   default-scheduler  Successfully assigned storagenfs/nfs-subdir-external-provisioner-588b7bc96f-qdhnm to wrkub01
Normal   Pulling    17m (x4 over 20m)     kubelet            Pulling image "registry.k8s.io/sig-storage/nfs-subdir-external-provisioner:v4.0.2"
Warning  Failed     17m (x4 over 20m)     kubelet            Failed to pull image "registry.k8s.io/sig-storage/nfs-subdir-external-provisioner:v4.0.2": rpc error: code = DeadlineExceeded desc = failed to pull and unpack image "registry.k8s.io/sig-storage/nfs-subdir-external-provisioner:v4.0.2": failed to resolve reference "registry.k8s.io/sig-storage/nfs-subdir-external-provisioner:v4.0.2": failed to do request: Head "https://registry.k8s.io/v2/sig-storage/nfs-subdir-external-provisioner/manifests/v4.0.2": dial tcp 34.96.108.209:443: i/o timeout
